# How can I programmatically find a suitable region to reload an unloaded module without overlap?

Tags: windbg, dbgeng

I am working on a windbg extension for dump analysis that requires symbols from unloaded modules. I'm using the function [IDebugSymbols3::Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugsymbols3-reload), which is analogous to the `.reload` command. In the case that the region originally occupied by the module is no longer available, I must explicitly specify a new base address to load into.

If I were manually debugging, I would probably use the `!address` extension to list free regions and look for one that was large enough. How I can programmatically find an appropriate location in the target's address space to use?

Answer (score 0):

GetNumberModules(), for count of loaded and unloaded modules
GetModuleParameters  in a loop for base and size

or maybe
IDebugDataSpaces2::QueryVirtual

```
#include <engextcpp.cpp>
#define MAX_MOD 0x100
class EXT_CLASS : public ExtExtension
{
public:
    EXT_COMMAND_METHOD(getoff);
};
EXT_DECLARE_GLOBALS();
EXT_COMMAND(getoff,"","")
{
    ULONG Loaded = 0;
    ULONG UnLoaded = 0;
    m_Symbols->GetNumberModules(&Loaded,&UnLoaded);
    Out("No of Loaded Modules =%u\n" ,Loaded);
    Out("No of UnLoaded Modules =%u\n" ,UnLoaded);
    DEBUG_MODULE_PARAMETERS Mdprm[MAX_MOD] = {0}; //fix
    if(Loaded < MAX_MOD) 
    {
        for(ULONG i=0;i< Loaded;i++)
        {
            m_Symbols->GetModuleParameters(1,NULL,i,&Mdprm[i]);            
            Out("Base&Size Mod %2u %16I64x %8x\n",i,Mdprm[i].Base,Mdprm[i].Size);
        }
    }    
}
```

compiled and linked with vs2017 dev cmd prompt on win7 x86 using 18362 includes

```
E:\sdk\getoff>cat complink.bat
cl /LD /nologo /W4 /Ox  /Zi /EHsc /IE:\windjs\windbg_18362\inc %1.cpp /link /EXPORT:DebugExtensionInitialize /Export:%1 /Export:help /RELEASE
```

resulting in

```
0:000> .load ./getoff.dll
0:000> !getoff
No of Loaded Modules =38
No of UnLoaded Modules =0
Base&Size Mod  0            90000    28000
Base&Size Mod  1         64ce0000   5e1000
Base&Size Mod  2         656c0000   190000
Base&Size Mod  3         65f80000    82000
Base&Size Mod  4         66010000    dc000
Base&Size Mod  5         662b0000     3000
Base&Size Mod  6         662c0000     5000
Base&Size Mod  7         662d0000     3000
Base&Size Mod  8         662f0000     3000
Base&Size Mod  9         66310000    10000
Base&Size Mod 10         66320000     3000
Base&Size Mod 11         667b0000     3000
Base&Size Mod 12         667c0000     3000
Base&Size Mod 13         66e80000     4000
Base&Size Mod 14         687d0000     4000
Base&Size Mod 15         68820000     4000
Base&Size Mod 16         68830000     3000
Base&Size Mod 17         68840000     3000
Base&Size Mod 18         6a200000     3000
Base&Size Mod 19         6a300000     3000
Base&Size Mod 20         6a340000     3000
Base&Size Mod 21         6a900000    10000
Base&Size Mod 22         6e660000     3000
Base&Size Mod 23         73b30000     4000
Base&Size Mod 24         74510000    2f000
Base&Size Mod 25         74890000     3000
Base&Size Mod 26         756f0000    17000
Base&Size Mod 27         75bc0000    4a000
Base&Size Mod 28         75f10000     a000
Base&Size Mod 29         761f0000    d4000
Base&Size Mod 30         76330000   15c000
Base&Size Mod 31         764d0000    c9000
Base&Size Mod 32         76790000    a1000
Base&Size Mod 33         76840000    9d000
Base&Size Mod 34         778b0000    8f000
Base&Size Mod 35         77940000    ac000
Base&Size Mod 36         779f0000   13c000
Base&Size Mod 37         77b40000    4e000
0:000>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This wasn't quite my question though. I had the info about where the unloaded module was loaded and its size. My situation was: I wanted to tell the engine to reload an unloaded module but the memory that it previously occupied was now (partially) filled with another module. In this case you have to manually choose another location to load it into.

Comment: I think my question might be moot for a dump file. When I actually tested reloading the module into an arbitrary free area in the address space, it failed. Since this is not a live target, I'm not really sure how allocation would work.

I ended up just using the Sym*** APIs to load the symbols separately from the host. This works but does make it more difficult to resolve symbols since I have to first determine which place to get the symbols from.